# Como optimizar mi lista de numeros?

Tags: java, netbeans, bucles

Mi tarea a realizar es la siguiente: hacer un programa en donde se pidan numeros hasta que se teclee uno negativo y mostrar cuantos numeros se han introducido.

El código que yo ejecute es el siguiente:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

 int a,b,c,d;

 a=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite un numero"));
 b=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite otro numero"));
 c=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite otro numero"));
 d=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite otro numero"));

 if(a>0&&b>0){

 if(c>0&&d>0){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Acontinuacion el listado de los 
      numeros que
      digitaste:\n"
     +a+"\n"+b+"\n"+c+"\n"+d);
     }
   }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar un bucle y un array de enteros:

```
int[] Numeros= new int[50]; //donde 50 es el maximo de numeros que puede almacenar
int contador=0; //utilizado para controlar la ubicacion donde se almacenará el siguiente numero.
int numeroactual=1;
while(numeroactual>0&&contador<50)
{
numeroactual=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite un numero")); 
Numeros[contador]=numeroactual;
contador++;
}
String msgNumeros="";
for (int i = 0; i <= contador; i++) {
msgNumeros+=Numeros[i]+"\n";
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Acontinuacion el listado de los numeros que digitaste:\n" +msgNumeros);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. De esta forma puedo optimizar mi programa sin necesidad de escribir muchas línea de codigo. En realidad me falta mucho por aprender sobre todo los arreglos.